# Adding ebook format (epub/mobi) support to document viewer

Tags: epub, mobi

Is there any way to add support for epub & mobi to the default document viewer in Ubuntu?

Calibre is an overkill for me there is any other small and light software out there?

Comment: You can use ``ebook-viewer`` from command line. It is part of calibre, but is simple to use. Just type ``ebook-viewer file.epub`` in console and it will open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use FBReader.  FBReader is a multi-platform e-book reader.

> supports several open e-book formats: fb2, html, chm, plucker,
>   palmdoc, ztxt, tcr (psion text), rtf, oeb, openreader, non-DRM'ed
>   mobipocket, plain text, epub, eReader<sup>1</sup>

You can download and install from the Ubuntu Software Center, or click the image below:

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Apps](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/fbreader/)</sup>